# Is http traffic from a gcp load balancer with psc backend configured secure? (to Apigee)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, apigee, google-vpc

I have a gcp load balancer, which terminates SSL.

I want the loadbalancer backend service to be Apigee, but prefer to avoid the hassle of installing ssl certs in Apigee. Therefore, traffic from the LB to Apigee is planned to be http, not https.

The connection from the gcp lb to Apigee uses a PSC.

Can the http traffic from the LB to Apigee be intercepted, or can it be seen as "secure"?

Answer (score 1):

Private Service Connect(PSC) creates a secure connection between your VPC and Google or third parties using the internal network; it also allows you to enforce security policies for restricting unwanted traffic. It is always suggested to follow best practices while configuring your [psc to apigee](https://cloud.google.com/apigee/docs/api-platform/architecture/southbound-networking-patterns-endpoints) when you are implementing this on your production environments, for testing and poc purposes you can implement the above solution.